# TypeError: Indexed expression has to be a type, mapping or array (is function (uint16) returns (uint256))?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, contract-design

Full source:https://github.com/laronlineworld/bettingMatch/blob/main/bettingMatch.sol
This is a Betting Smart Contract, trying to create a mapping structure that user/wallet_address can bet on multiple matches. The problem of this betting contract is every time the user/wallet_address place a bet, the data of single mapping overwrite, how to create a mapping of value so that user/wallet_address can bet on different matches.

Place bet function:

```
function bet(uint16 _matchSelected, uint16 _resultSelected) public payable {
   require(matchBettingActive[_matchSelected], "Betting: match voting is disabled");
  //Check if the player already exist
  //   require(!checkIfPlayerExists(msg.sender));

  //Check if the value sended by the player is higher than the min value
  require(msg.value >= minimumBet);
  
   
  //Set the player informations : amount of the bet, match and result selected
  playerInfo[msg.sender].amountBet = msg.value;
  playerInfo[msg.sender].matchSelected = _matchSelected;
  playerInfo[msg.sender].resultSelected = _resultSelected;
  
  //Add the address of the player to the players array
  players.push(msg.sender);
  
  MatchID[] storage bets = matchDetails[_matchSelected];
  bets.push(MatchID(msg.sender, _matchSelected, msg.value, _resultSelected))-1;
  
  uint16[] storage userBets = userToBets[msg.sender];
  userBets.push[_matchSelected];

  //Finally increment the stakes of the team selected with the player bet
  if ( _resultSelected == 1){
      totalBetHome[_matchSelected] += msg.value;
  }
  else if( _resultSelected == 2){
      totalBetAway[_matchSelected] += msg.value;
  }
  else{
      totalBetDraw[_matchSelected] += msg.value;
  }
```

}

also need to sync the data in reward distribution depending of matchID
distribution function:

```
function distributePrizes(uint16 matchFinished, uint16 teamWinner) public onlyOwner {
  address[1000] memory winners;
  //Temporary in memory array with fixed size. Let's choose 1000
  uint256 count = 0; // This is the count for the array of winners
  uint256 loserBet = 0; //This will take the value of all losers bet
  uint256 winnerBet = 0; //This will take the value of all winners bet
  address add;
  uint256 bets;
  address playerAddress;

  //Check who selected the winner team
  for(uint256 i = 0; i < players.length; i++){
     playerAddress = players[i];
     //If the player selected the winner team, we add his address to the winners array
     if(playerInfo[playerAddress].matchSelected == matchFinished &&
        playerInfo[playerAddress].resultSelected == teamWinner){
        winners[count] = playerAddress;
        count++;
     }
   }
   //We define which bet sum is the Loser one and which one is the winner
   if ( teamWinner == 1){
     loserBet = totalBetAway[matchFinished] + totalBetDraw[matchFinished];
     winnerBet = totalBetHome[matchFinished];
   }
   else if ( teamWinner == 2){
     loserBet = totalBetHome[matchFinished] + totalBetDraw[matchFinished];
     winnerBet = totalBetAway[matchFinished];
   }
   else{
      loserBet = totalBetHome[matchFinished] + totalBetAway[matchFinished];
      winnerBet = totalBetDraw[matchFinished];
   }
  //We loop through the array of winners, to give ethers to the winners
  for(uint256 j = 0; j < count; j++){
      //Check that the address in this fixed array is not empty
     if(winners[j] != address(0))
        add = winners[j];
        bets = playerInfo[add].amountBet;
        uint256 amountToPlayer = (bets * (10000+(loserBet*devFee/winnerBet))) / 10000;
        winners[j].transfer(amountToPlayer);
  }
  //Reset all variables
  delete playerInfo[playerAddress]; 
  players.length = 0; 
  loserBet = 0; 
  winnerBet = 0;
  //10 will be the number of matches (To improve this)
  for(uint256 k = 0; k < 10; k++){
     totalBetHome[k] = 0;
     totalBetAway[k] = 0;
     totalBetDraw[k] = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are mapping an address to a single `Player` struct that hold a single bet

```
struct Player {           // <--- A better name would be Bet
  uint256 amountBet;
  uint16 matchSelected;
  uint16 resultSelected;
}

mapping(address => Player) public playerInfo;
```

You could use a Player array to store multiple bets.

```
mapping(address => Player[]) public playerInfo;
```